# drop table with patterns in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

when I use this code in terminal

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name LIKE '%CS%';
```

I get result as DROP TABLE 10CSA,10CSB;

But when I use the same inside `mysql_query();` statement in a php page,the tables with above table names doesn't get dropped, any solution for this?

Comment: Because you can only drop one table at a time

Comment: tried with single table also..

Comment: I recall table names cannot start with numbers. You need to escape them with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

As Juergen points out, `delete` only applies to one table at a time.  Instead, generate multiple statements:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', table_name , ';' ) AS statement
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name LIKE '%CS%';
```

Copy all of them, to delete one table at a time.

If you want to do this inside an application, then read one row at a time from the result set in a loop and execute the statement.

Comment: i want to write that inside a php page,,how do I?

Comment: @PramodMandicha: By writing down the code for it. Just take the database driver of your choice and fire it up. Take extra care when programming cod that deletes things.

Comment: I got a Solution...I tried something like this,,  $sql="SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'test' AND table_name LIKE '_CS_';";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $code=$row[0];
  }
  mysql_query($code);